# Question about Eurofighter structure

Tags: aircraft-structures, plane-construction, eurofighter-typhoon

I was researching for the Eurofighter and I came up with a picture of its structure. I have three questions about its parts. I can't understand the **role** and the **usage** of them. Can anyone help me?

These 3 parts are the following:

- Radar mounting bulkhead
- Strobe light/anti-collision beacon
- Engine bleed-air primary heat exchanger

*All of them are circled with a different color from me so to be focused and easy to find them. Also, their definition exists in the picture but I would like to also know, as I mentioned above, their role and their usage.

**PICTURE**

[image]

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Radar mounting bulkhead: this is the vertical plate to which the radar antenna is attached. This is just a structure.
- Strobe light/anti-collision beacon: this is a [bright light that flashes to make the aircraft more visible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_light#Aviation_navigation_lights) and prevent collisions.
- Engine bleed-air primary heat exchanger: this is a [heat exchanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_exchanger) for [bleed air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_air) from the engine. Bleed air from the engine is hot and needs to be cooled down for various applications, this cooling down is done in the heat exchanger.

It's quite easy these days to find out what an unknown term means. Just go to Wikipedia and enter the unknown term into the search box.